# Created Custom Control and add it to a ListView in Xamarin. But it only fired when I double click. I want ItemTapped to fire on single click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a custom ViewCell object in my Xamarin project.  I have no custom code-behind in it.  I have a ViewModel that is a BindableBase.  It just takes in the values I need for my control.

Here is the Custom control. In the end I just need to get a string stored in the ViewModel when it is tapped so I can navigate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PhantomLib.CustomControls;assembly=PhantomLib"
          xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:PhantomLib.Extensions;assembly=PhantomLib"
          x:Class="Fulfillment.UI.StoreSelection.StoreCell">
    <controls:RoundedFrame Style="{StaticResource RoundedFramePrimary}" extensions:Views.TapBackgroundColor="{DynamicResource LightishGrey}">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="{Binding StoreLabel}" Style="{StaticResource TitleLeftBlack}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
            <Image Source="icon_forward" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource ArrowImageStyle}"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <controls:RoundedFrame.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style x:Key="ArrowImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="RoundedFramePrimary" TargetType="controls:RoundedFrame">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="RoundTopLeft" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="RoundBottomLeft" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"  Value="{DynamicResource White}"/>
                    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="80" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,0,0,15"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </controls:RoundedFrame.Resources>
    </controls:RoundedFrame>
</ViewCell>
```

In my main page, I have the following ListView

```
        <ListView x:Name="StoreList" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false" HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding StoreItems}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SeparatorVisibility="None"
            SelectionMode="None" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource storeItemTemplate}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <behavior:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding StoreTappedCommand}"  Converter="{StaticResource TappedItemConverter}"/>
            </ListView.Behaviors>
```

Then in the ViewModel for the Page I add my items with the following code

```
    List<string> stores = _settings.GetStores();

    foreach (string store in stores)
    {
        StoreCellViewModel tempStore = new StoreCellViewModel(store);

        StoreItems.Add(tempStore);
    }
```

I can't seem to find any reason that it would require me to double click an item in the ListView to fire the StoreTappedCommand.

Comment: Why not add the ItemTapped event to ViewCell?  And your question is fire the ItemTapped event with a double click?

Comment: I have updated the question, it was poorly worded. The problem is that I want a normal single click, but right now it's only firing the ItemTapped if I double tap it. I feel like some other UI component is getting the first tap or something.

Comment: After a bit more trial and error, I did finally get it to work right with moving the ItemTapped into my ViewCell. Thank you!